# How can I share global configuration fields when writing a jenkins plugin?

Tags: plugins, jenkins, share

I'm currently writing a jenkins plug-in that has multiple builders. I wanted to share the fields in the descriptor/global.jelly across all builders. How can I share this information? Can I use inheritance or encapsulation?

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start is to search the Jenkins [github repository](https://github.com/jenkinsci)

The code you want is

```
Jenkins.getInstance().getDescriptor( MyPluginWithGlobalConfig.class )
```

Which will give you the descriptor back you want (as there is only one instance of the descriptor)

Here is one I used in a [plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/selenium-axis-plugin) (in groovy) which fetches a descriptor then calls a method on it [source file](https://github.com/jenkinsci/selenium-axis-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/jenkinsci/plugins/SeleniumDynamicCapability.groovy)

```
@Override
public List<String> rebuild(List<String> list){
    SeleniumDynamicCapability.DescriptorImpl sdcd = Jenkins.getInstance().getDescriptor(SeleniumDynamicCapability.class)

    List<SeleniumCapabilityRO> sc = sdcd.loadDefaultItems()

    if (sc.size() == 0)
        throw(new SeleniumException("No selenium capabilities detected"))

    setSeleniumCapabilities(sc)

    sc.each{list.add(it.toString())}
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Just in case, please also note that for plugin with global config, it's better to extend the dedicated [GlobalConfiguration class](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/?jenkins/model/GlobalConfiguration.html), as [Plugin](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/?jenkins/model/Plugin.html) overriding has recently [been deprecated](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/commit/3a83504e3d08f5eb5b9787d9810f8cd40167dc10).